# Why Gitkraken does not display any logs in big repos?

Tags: git, git-log, gitkraken

I have a quite big repo with exactly `26731` commits, the `GitKraken` does not show any logs for this repo. It works fine on other repos but **not in this repo**, although it recognizes the branches and tags but **it does not display any logs in any branch** (as the below image).

[image]

#### Things I have tried but didn't work:

1. Adjust the preference to display all logs.
2. Remove the `~/.gitkraken` folder (to clear any destructive caches if any exists).
3. Uninstall/Install the GitKraken with the latest version.

#### Environment details:

- **OS:** `Linux 4.15.0-70-generic x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- **RAM:** `8GB`
- **CPU:** `intel core-i7`
- **GitKraken's version:** `6.3.1`

#### Question:

How to make the GitKraken display the log's tree?

Comment: Does [support logs](https://support.gitkraken.com/known-issues/error-logs/) give any indication of an error ?

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari no nothing! :| It simply does not display the logs!

Comment: Are you using the free version ?

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari No, I am not. As I said before my other **private repos'** log are displaying. I only have issues with this one.

Comment: Maybe the support team could help, as per [this](https://www.gitkraken.com/contact) they claim __For guaranteed email support, upgrade to GitKraken Pro.__

Comment: Similar to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/59021836

Comment: This looks like a bug. If you haven't already, can you reach out to support@gitkraken.com so we can try to diagnose the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted a solution for a similar problem in [Gitkraken doesn't show branches and commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59021836/gitkraken-doesnt-show-branches-and-commits). But the problem described here lies closer to what my situation was.

I had a bloated repo that timed out if I tried to clone it, similar to your case.
You can succesfully clone it with

> git clone http://github.com/large-repository --depth 1

If you are not interested in the history. If you want to pull the history in later, run

> git fetch --unshallow

(To any mods that feel this is a duplicate question to the one mentioned above then close the question, not the answer)

Comment: `To any mods that feel this is a duplicate question to the one mentioned above then close the question, not the answer` why on earth closing an accepted solution to a question? the action would make the question remain unanswered while it got the answer!

Comment: A small update, I got a response from GitKraken's dev team:
 
*"Thank you for using GitKraken! This is currently a feature request, as GitKraken does not support shallow repositories (cloning with the --depth flag from the CLI git). You would want to clone the entire repository in order to view it and work with the repo in GitKraken. I have also noted your interest in seeing this feature added to GitKraken."*

So hopefully shallow copies will be better supported in the future; for now the fetch is a good workaround.